# using command line arguement with redirecting

Tags: io-redirection

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        int val;

        if(argc!=2)
        {
                printf("Usage: %s <descriptor> \n", argv[0]);
                exit(1);
        }

        val=fcntl(atoi(argv[1]), F_GETFL, 0);


        switch(val & O_ACCMODE)
        {
                case O_RDONLY:
                        printf("read only");
                        break;
                case O_WRONLY:
                        printf("write only");
                        break;
                case O_RDWR:
                        printf("read write");
                        break;
                default:
                        printf("unknown access mode");
        }

        if(val & O_APPEND)
                printf(", append");
        if(val & O_NONBLOCK)
                printf(", nonblocking");
        if(val & O_SYNC)
                printf(", synchronous writes");

        putchar('\n');
        exit(0);
 }
```

I have this code. Anyway, source is fully understandable.

But, I got confused using this program with command line argument with redirecting.

using this program and result are following

```
    $ ./a.out 0 < /dev/tty
    read only
    $ ./a.out 1 > temp.foo
    $ cat temp.foo
    write only
    $ ./a.out 2 2>>temp.foo
    write only, append
    $ ./a.out 5 5<>temp.foo
    read write
```

I know how to do redirecting, but using this technique with command line argument is so confusing. I don't know anything.

Well, in my knowledge, this program gets 1 argument which is file descriptor number.

So, when I use this program like

```
$ ./a.out 0
read write
$ ./a.out 1
read write
$ ./a.out 2
read write
```

This is ok. stdin, stdout, stderr file status is `read write`.

But when I use this command with redirecting. I don't know what mechanism is doing.

For example:

```
./a.out 0 < /dev/tty
```

Here, `/dev/tty` file is now same as standard input, so 0 means `/dev/tty` after all?

And, what's the difference between `&2` ,`&1` and `2`, `1` when we use redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to do redirecting, but using this technique with command line argument is so confusing. I don't know anything.

Please describe more detailed what exactly confuses you. As for me, the results are very expected: if a file object is opened for read-only (as '<' redirection does), F_GETFL will give O_RDONLY. The same for other types of redirections.

Without redirection, a child command gets the same standard descriptiors as the parent shall has. In a typical interactive case, it's the user terminal and all descriptors are in read-write. It's decided useless to make them read-only, write-only, etc. because it's more convenient to use the same descriptor for interactive terminal activity (as e.g. full-screen activity with `curses`), than to split it between 0 for terminal input, 1 for terminal output, etc.; but this isn't extended for user-specified redirections. Is that the thing you asked?

> And, what's the difference between &2 ,&1 and 2, 1 when we use redirecting?

If you mean forms like `2>1` and `2>&1`, they are principally different. `2>1` redirects 2 as writing to file `1`. `2>&1` redirects 2 as copy of descriptor 1 (on C level, this is `dup2(1,2)`). Both `n<&m` and `n>&m` for numeric n, m are identical and don't add restriction to access mode.